# Mysql get the latest posts from tables BUT check if its labeled hidden

Tags: php, mysql, database, hidden

I have a SQL that finds the latest post from all the different categories and echo them out.

But it can happen that the latest post from that category has a table named **`hidden`** with a value of **`1`** (instead of **`0`** which is visible).

I don't want it to display that one but find another post from that category which is **not** hidden.

```
SELECT m1.* 
FROM dbcontent m1 
LEFT JOIN dbcontent m2 ON (m1.category_name = m2.category_name AND m1.date_create < m2.date_create) 
WHERE m2.date_create IS NULL 
AND NOT m1.hidden > 0
ORDER BY c_id ASC"
```

The SQL above simply ignores the whole category if it's marked as hidden, but does not check if there is another older post from that category that it can display which has the value **`hidden = 0`**.

Comment: 1.Don't format you SQL statement in that way put in the code style 2.Use enum instead the 0/1, or if you want to use the 0/1 use bit don't use int. 3.And this part  'AND NOT m1.hidden > 0' make no sense. You should read this('MySql Cookbook Paul DuBois') book about mysql.It's a great reference from where to start of...Good luck

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the query has conflicting conditions, i.e. `m1.date_create < m2.date_create` and `m2.date_create IS NULL`, these both won't be true at the same time.

If you want to get the latest non hidden item per category then you can use a sub query like the one below (you don't even need a `JOIN`):

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbcontent
WHERE post_id in (
 SELECT post_id, category_name, MAX(date_create)
 FROM dbcontent
 WHERE hidden = 0
 GROUP BY post_id, category_name
);
```